# In SSRS, is it possible to set the AutoRefresh value to an expression?

Tags: reporting-services

I've set up a report using SSRS and would like it to AutoRefresh constantly as data will continuously be added. Simple solution was to set the value to a constant which is easy enough. However, the report is an error log so I would like for the user to be able to shut it off or delay the refresh while they read the messages. I've tried adding a parameter Refresh as an Integer but I cannot set the AutoRefresh value to an expression via

```
=Parameters!Refresh.Value
```

and

```
=[@Refresh]
```

SSRS yells at me saying the "Property value is not valid. PARAM is not a valid value for Int32."

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AutoRefresh can use an expression in SSRS 2012.

I was able to set this up correctly on SSRS 2012 and make it work. The data type of the parameter must be Integer. What data type are you using? What version of SSRS are you using?

Edit: I have confirmed it does NOT work in SSRS 2008. However, if you are using SSRS 2008 R2, change the project property TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2008 R2, and it will work. I have it working in a test environment.

Comment: I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 and my parameter type is Integer.

Comment: It seems as if the parameters are out of the scope of the report properties.

Comment: Ok - I tried this on a SSRS 2008 R2 instance and got the following error message: Using an expression to set the AutoRefresh property is not supported in SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services. Set AutoRefresh to an integer (int32) value or change the ReportServerTargetVersion to a version that supports setting AutoRefresh by using an expression.

Comment: I changed the project property TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2008 R2 and it works correctly for me.

Comment: Thank you for the help Stacia! My TargetServerVersion was initially set to SQL Server 2008 R2. So I changed it to SQL Server 2008, built, ran it, and received the error you mentioned above. I then changed it back to SQL Server 2008 R2 and it works not.